Young-adult or Children's book about a boy that goes to a school where the principal is the devil
I do not remember what the book was even about, or if it was originally in English or Spanish (I read it in Spanish when I was younger), but it talked about a boy that went to an institute where he and his friends discovered that the principal was the Devil??? Or some sort of demon.
The book then had a prequel about the same school, and the same boy with his friends, only that this time around three sisters transfer to the institute, who then the boy discovers were some sort of snake?? Lizard?? They were demons as well.
Something noticeable about the books were the covers: at least in the Spanish version, they were reflective? One angle showed a picture of the principal as a normal (white) man, but if you looked at the picture from a different angle, the picture of the principal then turned to him having red skin, with horns and fangs (resembling the Devil).
I have no idea if the book even exists (even though I clearly remember reading it up until midnight) but if you think you know to, please help me out.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately what year would you have read this?

Initial one that comes to mind is The Demon Headmaster.

@user25730 - That was mind-control though. It's also not made explicit what he was, although most people think he was some sort of alien

@DavidW I don't know how to answer directly to your question, so I'll post it as a comment. I think I read the book around the ages of 12 and 14. I was born in 2004 so the year must have been between 2016 and 2018, but I don't think the book was from the year, it was older (but i'm not sure). I really hope this helps you. Thank you so much.
